# Access method on multiple obects in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'd like to call a method on mutliple objects from a realted obejct. I can do this, but it isn't ideal as I would like to use the method already on the object, which does more than just update fields (loggin etc.):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def deactivate(self):
        self.status = 'inactive'
        logger.info('The category %s has been deactivated.' % (self.name))
        Items.objects.filter(Category=self).update(status='inactive')
        logger.info('The items in category %s have been deactivated.' % (self.name)

class Items(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def deactivate(self):
        self.status = 'inactive'
        logger.info('The item %s has been deactivated.' % (self.name))
```

So instead of `Items.objects.filter(Category=self).update(status='inactive')` i'd prefer something like `Items.objects.filter(Category=self).deactivate()`.

Is this possible without looping through all the records?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I concerned you should be able to do that with the [`Managers`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/). You can also find more info in [this blog post](http://blog.almabase.com/post/81279822390/using-django-model-managers-for-dynamic-behaviour)

Comment: Could you reconstruct what I am trying to achieve with the `Managers` as you mention above? Thanks